# how to use htaccess to chance the URL...?

Tags: .htaccess

I googled and looked on stackover flow but i failed to really understand the answers

I;m not trying to REDIRECT but CHANGE the WAY the URLS LOOK

I want to change a these into the new urls

www.site.com/abc.php to www.site.com/
(my index page currently has my login page so I can't use the index.php)

www.site.com/abc.php#123.php to www.site.com/123.php

UPDATE:

Ok, how can I do this then

www.site.com/abc.php to www.site.com/abc/

so that when a hash link is present it looks like

www.site.com/abc/#123.pho

or if possible

www.site.com/abc/#123/

Comment: If the browser sees a URL with a #fragment in it, the fragment part never gets sent to the server, so you can't do any processing server-side based on it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to the other answer on redirects, if you want more advanced forwarding you can use the Apache RewriteEngine module.
You can then use regexps, which may include subpatterns.

Example from my site, I created the patterns after I've imported everything from blogger to wordpress. Whenever someone visits an URL like http://www.twistedmind.nu/2006_03_01_archive.html he'd be redirected to http://twistedmind.nu/2006/03

RewriteEngine on
RedirectMatch 301 (([0-9]*)_([0-9]*)_([0-9]*)(.*)(.html))$ http://twistedmind.nu/$2/$3/
RedirectMatch 301 (([0-9]*)(.*)(.html))$ http://twistedmind.nu/$1

Based on the other answer, you can't match on everything that's after the hash tag # though.

Other example (added after comment):

RedirectMatch 301 (.*).php$ http://www.mysite.com/$1

This should strip the .php extension from all links, the new link (withouth .php) should exist.

You can use mod_rewrite if you want to create 'virtual' urls that redirect something like mysample to mysample.php. See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/mod_rewrite.html for an explanation.

Comment: Minor note, the rewriting currently does not work on my site, I think my htaccess file got lost some time ago.

Comment: heh, well i'm not trying to redirect but just change the way the url looks. I guess I can't do anything about the hashmarks, how can I rename .php to '/' and if a user types in abc to redirect them to abc/

Answer (score 0):

You can use an .htaccess only for the first url.

```
Redirect /abc.php http://www.site.com/
```

The second url cannot be redirected with the .htaccess. 
You can use javascript for that:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if (location.hash == "123")
        location.href = location.hash+".php";
</script>
```

Comment: i'm not looking to redirect, but rather change the way the url looks.