# how to rewrite url for this query string url in htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have tried many rewrite rules for the following url but i didn't get any success.I researched a lot and wasted my 2 days.

I need this url to be like this
I need to rewrite url from

http://localhost/tour/tour.php?page=golden-triangle-tour

to

http://localhost/tour/tour/golden-triangle-tour

Please guide me to fix this in htaccess.

Comment: "I have tried many rewrite rules"  what are?

Comment: Just to be clear, you want the url with the .php in it to be rewritten to the lower url? Or redirected?

Comment: This looks like you miss understood the concept of rewriting. Rewriting does _not_ allow you to somehow magically convert the output of your application so that links look better or are more search engine friendly. You have to do that yourself in your logic. Rewriting allows to to rewrite _incoming_ requests to your http server such that you can translate some url like the second version you posted to the internal version like the first example you posted which can be handled by your script. So (usually) rewriting is used to convert the second form to the first, so opposite of your request.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to use htaccess to chance the URL...?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4345056/how-to-use-htaccess-to-chance-the-url)

Comment: This question is different .. otherwise i wouldn't be asking here twice brother.www.site.com/abc.php#123.php to www.site.com/123.php

UPDATE:

Ok, how can I do this then

www.site.com/abc.php to www.site.com/abc/

Answer (score 2):

You can use this code in your `/tour/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /tour/

# external redirect from actual URL to pretty one
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /tour\.php\?page=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ tour/%1? [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /tour/(.+?)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=302,L,NE]

# internal forward from pretty URL to actual one
RewriteRule ^tour/([^/.]+)/?$ tour.php?page=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

# To internally forward /dir/file to /dir/file.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/toure/$1\.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: Many many Thanks.It worked like a charm.You are really a geek.

Comment: hello .I am really happy but i need all sites url to be like this. http://localhost/tour/about.php to http://localhost/tour/about.. can you make edits to existing one.I will mark you as accepted .

Comment: No it says 404 error.I need just url like http://localhost/tour/about.php to http://localhost/tour/about

Comment: But that is a different question from what you asked above. It is not good practice to add new questions via comments. My previous answer was for the original question you asked.

Comment: ya your previous question is really helpful..and i fixed that in my your edited htaccess..now it worked fine.thanks

Comment: Added a rule to hide .php in the answer.

Comment: If it worked out, you may mark the answer as accepted by clicking on tick mark on top-left of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Another  solution :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page=([^&]+) [NC] 
RewriteRule ^tour.php$ /tour/%1? [NC,R,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^tour/([^/]+)/?$ /tour.php?page=$1 [QSA,L,NC]
```

Comment: Actually this will cause infinite looping since both rules will keep triggering each other.